# Error of "missing \item" in enumerate when using custom bullets?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm using `enumerate` to type up homework solutions, based on the following MWE. When I remove the `[(a)]` from the `enumerate`, there isn't an error, but when I add it, I get the "perhaps a missing `\item`" error. How can I fix this? I don't want to add an `\item` in front of the solution, since it isn't part of the list per se, and I don't want to remove the custom bullet because in my full document, this is part of a nested list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item $n(n+1)/2 \in O(n^3)$

True, because $n(n+1)/2$ is of order 2, which is less than order 3. 

\item $n(n+1)/2 \in O(n^2)$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate), since it redefines the `enumerate` environment to manage an optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item $n(n+1)/2 \in O(n^3)$

True, because $n(n+1)/2$ is of order 2, which is less than order 3. 

\item $n(n+1)/2 \in O(n^2)$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

A similar format would have been achieved with the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
%...
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  %...
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Thank you, adding `\usepackage{enumerate}` fixed the error in the MWE, and I fixed the additional problem that was occurring in my full example. (I had a `\` in place of a `/`).